# Return different datatypes crystal formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a requirement where depending on the parameter selected the table field should be displayed as text or date. For eg, if the user selects a true, the OriginDate field which is a datetime type should be displayed as a date in the report else should be displayed as a text. I tried creating a formula an doing something like below, and then placing the formula in the details section of the report but it doesnt work due to different datatypes returned.

```
if {?Mailmerge}=true then
ToText({Travel.OriginDatetime}, "M/d/yy")
else
{Travel.OriginDatetime}
```

Is there a way I can accompalish the above requirement so that I do not end up creating 2 reports one with field displayed as text and other as date?

Comment: The date is displayed as text either way; what are you trying to accompish?

Comment: No the above doesnt work, because Travel.OriginDatetime is a field in database with datatype datetime. So when I try to save the formula it gives me an error saying a string is required for the Travel.OriginDatetime line. I added it above to give an idea of what I was trying to accompalish.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand.  If they're stored as dates in the database, what is the point of showing the date as a string?  Are you trying to format the date differently?

Comment: ok I will explain. Basically if the field is shown as date, when the report is exported to excel and used for mailmerge, it displays datetime. So what I am trying to do is if Mailmerge parameter is selected as false, the OriginDatetime field is displayed the way it is in the database. But when Mailmerge is selected as True it displays the date part of the field but as a string. So when it is used in mailmerge after exporting to excel it only displays date and doesnt add a timestamp to it.

Comment: Basically for a datetime field that is formatted as a date in crystal when exported to excel becomes datetime instead of just date. So if it is converted to text and then displayed it wouldnt add time stamp to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a formula that returns your field as a string `totext({Travel.OriginDateTime},"M/d/yy")` and overlay it with the original field `{Travel.OriginDateTime}` and conditionally suppress them based on the value of `{?MailMerge}` such that only one shows in any one instance of the report.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Ryan. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you, you want to only show `M/d/yy` when `?MailMerge` is true, otherwise yuo want to show the full date?

You can't show different datatypes in the same formula, so just convert them both parts of the conditional statement into strings:

```
if {?Mailmerge}=true then
ToText({Travel.OriginDatetime}, "M/d/yy")  // 8/30/12
else
ToText({Travel.OriginDatetime}, "M/d/yy hh:mm:ss")  // 8/30/12 02:06:00
```

I don't know what exactly your dates look like in the database, but you can use the above as a guideline into formatting your date based on the `?MailMerge` parameter.

Comment: The above would convert both to text. I want to convert it to text only if Mailmerge is true else display as date field. I know I won't be able to show different datatypes in same formula but is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, it exports as datetime field to excel when I export it even though it is formatted as date in crystal.

Comment: I'm with LBT- convert the date to a string formatted however you want.  That's the difference in your output, not the data type, right?

Comment: @developer - I don't know what to tell you, it exports fine for me.

Comment: I am not sure why this happens but it adds a timestamp even for a date formatted field in crystal. So I thought of converting it to string. So it doesnt add the time part. But at the same time the report should also be sortable by date in excel. So both the functionalities are needed. So what I was thinking is creating a parameter Mailmerge which when false will display the field as date in cystal. This report will not be used for mailmerge so it is fine if it adds a time stamp to it when exported to Crystal.

Comment: If mailmerge is true, the field will be displayed as string. This time the report will not be date sortable but will not add a timestamp as well.

Comment: LBT, after exporting can click on cell that displays date field. When you look in the formula field above it will also show the time stamp.

Comment: @developer - it must be the version of Excel you are using then; if I export using `ToText({Travel.OriginDatetime}, "M/d/yy")`, then the cell contains `8/30/12`.

Comment: Does the formula field at the top also show 8/30/12 when you select that cell?